# Get the "child" object's Class in a final method?

Tags: java, inheritance

is it possible to access child **class** in parent?

e. g. I want the output of the following code tobe "red blue".

```
class Color {
    public final void printName() {
        System.out.println(__Something_Here!!!__.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}

class Red extends Color;

class Blue extends Color;

main() {
    Red red = new red();
    Blue blue = new blue();
    red.printName();
    blue.printName();
}
```

Comment: A `final` method has no bearing on the value of `this` or the actual object/instance the method is invoked upon. It merely dictates how the exact method to bind to is resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getClass()` to return the class object for any object.

```
public final void printName() {
    System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) for `getClass()` for details

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
class Color {
    public final void printName() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Every Java object by [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method can access all the class info.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you make `printName()` private. If it is protected, then you can call

```
Red red = new Red();
Blue blue = new Blue();
red.printName();
blue.printName();
```

and then call

```
System.out.println(this.class.getSimpleName());
```

As it is, private prohibits `Red` and `Blue` from inheriting the method.